# How many bytes does a phrase have in different encodings

Tags: encoding, utf-8, utf-16, iso-8859-1, utf-32

The task is - consider the Spanish phrase

```
 "¡Aquí!"
```

How many bytes will it have in the ISO-8859-1 encoding? How many in UTF-8? How many in UTF-16? How many in UTF-32?

My solution is

```
- ISO 8859-1 = 6 bytes
- UTF-8 =8 bytes
- UTF-16 = 12 bytes
- UTF-32 = 24 bytes
```

Is that right?

```
- ISO 8859-1 = 6 (6*1) (ISO 8859-1 is a single-byte encoding)

- UTF – 8 = 2+1+1+1+2+1=8 (1byte for ASCII character: A, q, u, ! are ASCII 
  characters    (0 till 127), ¡ and í are 2 bytes each, their values are 161 
  and 237 correspondingly).

- UTF16 = 12 (6*2) (2 bytes for 0-FFFF (65535)

- UTF32 = 24 (6*4) (4 bytes for everything)
```

Comment: Homework? At least tell us how you found the numbers.

Comment: yes, it`s a hometask. Is that bad?

Comment: Being homework is not neccessarily bad. Just follow the guidelines for asking questions even more stringently, and make it obvious by mentioning it concisely. (This one is obvious, but you should have said so.) The guideline where you fail imho, is asking a good question. Still, better than most, so +-0. As an aside, you got it right, if you do not count a terminator/count as well.

Answer (score 0):

> - ISO 8859-1 = 6 bytes
> - UTF-8 =8 bytes
> - UTF-16 = 12 bytes
> - UTF-32 = 24 bytes
>
> Is that right?

Yes.

(You've not considered the Byte Order Mark for UTF-16 and UTF-32, which would add two and four bytes respectively, but it's an acceptable answer for a homework question.)